# Want to display the processing progress using a Label to show a counter of sorts

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Its a label printing app. Desire to show progress via a counter displaying in a Label. ie.  would like it to
look like this... 1000 increments to 1001 increments to 1002, 1003 etc.  Pretty simple pgm so obviously processing from start to finish is instantaneous. Thus end number pops up right away rather than flashing a sequence of sorts. Don't need number to be readable but just simulating the process.  Since it is a printing program, there is time for this display. At the end of processing the final number should be on the screen. Thought maybe I could use a timer to tick off before updating label. My coding is obviously not correct. Here it is.  Any suggestions are appreciated. I am a 79 YO tinkerer programmer (worked back in the COBOL days) so be kind LOL.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ' Print button
    Dim toPrint As Integer = Me.NumericUpDown2.Value
    Dim RetVal As Object
    Dim TopPos As String = "375,200"
    Dim InfoPos As String = "360,260"
    startNo = TextBox2.Text
    For index As Integer = 1 To toPrint
        RetVal = RDP.PrintRawData("^XA^LL450^PQ" & arrCust(4) & "^CFB,30^FO" & TopPos & "^FD" & arrCust(5) & StartNo & "^FS^FO" & InfoPos & "^FD" & arrCust(2) & "^FS^XZ")
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
        startNo += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label4.Text = startNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Please paste the code part as text, not an image.

Comment: Please edit your question as pictures of code instead text code is a bad praxis (Take the tour and learn [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop never yields control back to the underlying windows event message pump, and so there's never a chance to process any paint messages to redraw the label until after everything is finished.

To fix this we first need to resolve two conflicting statements:

> from start to finish is instantaneous

and

> Since it is a printing program, there is time for this display.

*Only one of those two statements can be true.* They are mutually exclusive.

If the first statement is true, I'd change the timer to tick more often (every 200 milliseconds or so; faster is just wasteful) and put up with an ugly `Application.DoEvents` call in the loop so the label can have a chance to repaint. (Also: start the timer *once*, before entering the loop, and not on each iteration).

If the latter statement is true, I'll echo the usual warnings about avoiding `Application.DoEvents` (there are a lot of "gotchas" with this method). Instead, I'd do it the **right** way, and use a [`BackgroundWorker` component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0).

Comment: What I mean by "from start to finish is instantaneous" is that the computer  processing time is instantaneous.  Since the actual printing process can take from seconds to minutes or more, there is time to display the moving count on the screen.  Hope this helps,

Comment: Do you want the display to match what is happening on the printer?